# Can't run simple Swift app on iphone simulator: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain

Tags: swift, macos, virtualbox

VirtualBox 6.1

- Create virtual machine MacOS 10.15
- Install XCode Run XCode -
- Create new simple Swift project.

But when I try to run project on iPhone simulator I get error:

```
The request to open "com.myproject.swifttestproject.SwiftTestProject" failed.

Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain

Code: 5

Failure Reason: Unexpected error type.

User Info: {

    BSErrorCodeDescription = InvalidResponse;

}


The operation couldn’t be completed. (BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain error 3.)

Domain: BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain

Code: 3

User Info: {

    BSErrorCodeDescription = OperationFailed;

}



System Information

macOS Version 10.15.6 (Build 19G73)
Xcode 11.6 (16141)
```

Answer (score 0):

same thing. Created a virtual machine and ended up with the following:

```
The request to open "pv.calculator" failed.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 5
Failure Reason: Unexpected error type.
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = InvalidResponse;
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. (BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain error 3.)
Domain: BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain
Code: 3
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = OperationFailed;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.6 (Build 19G73)
Xcode 11.6 (16141)
```